# Query on $3^x \pm 2^{x-a}$ with relation to prime and semiprime

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, exponential-diophantine-equations, semiprimes, computational-number-theory

While doing some research(more closer to some playing) with the formula $3^x\pm2^{x-a}$ for $x\in \mathbb{N}$ and $ \{a\mid a \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0},\hspace{1mm} a\le (x-1)\}$ I've become to observe that there are many primes and semiprimes for each $x$ of the formula.

For example when $x=22$, we can find that $3^{22}-2^{x-a}$ being semiprime for $(x-a)\in\{21,19,9\}$, and $3^{22}+2^{x-a}$ being semiprime for $(x-a)\in\{22,20,18,17,15,14,13,8,6,5\}$.

Also we can find that $3^{22}-2^{15}$, $3^{22}-2^{7}$, $3^{22}-2^{3}$,$3^{22}-2^{1}$, $3^{22}+2^{2}$, $3^{22}+2^{19}$ being prime when $x=22$.

So I've come to expect the following two statements.

1. For $x\in \mathbb{N}$ and $ \{a\mid a \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0},\hspace{1mm} a\le (x-1)\}$, there are at least one semiprime for every $x$ among each set of $\{semiprime\in 3^x-2^{x-a}\}$ and $\{semiprime\in 3^x+2^{x-a}\}$.
2. For $x\in \mathbb{N}$ and $ \{a\mid a \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0},\hspace{1mm} a\le (x-1)\}$, there are at least one prime for every $x$ among the set of $\{\mathbb{P} \in 3^x\pm2^{x-a}\}$.

I've seen a lot of people who have astonishing mathematical abilities in this site so I've become to ask for some opinions with the statements above, of which I wouldn't be able to handle them since they are out of my reach otherwise.

Comment: Note that numbers of the form $3^m\pm 2^n$ with positive integers $m,n$ are coprime to $6$. Small numbers with this property have a good chance to be prime. Conjectures like the one you formulated are usually out of reach for a proof , but maybe heuristic arguments can be made. First step is checking the conjectures upto some limit. Did you do that ?

Comment: @Peter: Yup, that is why I did make the statement for the second one as being $\{\mathbb{P} \in 3^x\pm2^{x-a}\}$, not as the semiprime version which I've divided the set into $+$ one and $-$ one.

Comment: For the primes, the first counterexample is $m=28$. The smallest nonnegative integer $n$ such that $3^{28}\cdot 2^n+1$ is prime is $n=29$ whereas for $3^{28}\cdot 2^n-1$ is it $n=347$. But even the existence of a prime of the form $3^m\cdot 2^n\pm 1$ is not clear. If $m=634$ , for example, we must go until $n=1299$ to find a prime. I think chances for the semiprime-conjectures to hold (or at least to hold for sufficient large $m$) are better.

Comment: @Peter: Thanks. I've seen your list of questions and answers and they were impressive. Can you tell me how long have you been studied numbers?? Also could you share your information on what coding program fits you best for doing research on numbers? (Python, Fortran, Sagemath, etc...)  You don't have to reply these but I just wondered. Anyway, many thanks!

Comment: $(1)$ I use PARI/GP for number theory calculations (factoring , primality checking and similar things) $(2)$ I always was interested in numbers , I am in particular excited of the huge numbers (that do not occur in "daily life math") $(3)$ Shall I continue with the semiprimes ? For larger $m$, I think the search can be accelerated if we do not want to find the smallest example. Are you content with that ?

Comment: @Peter Why not? It would be my pleasure. I am happy to be refuted by some counterexample so I can forget it and move on to some other topic!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The semiprime-version is promising. I arrived at the following conjecture

> 

Suppose , $\ n\ge 4\ $ is an integer. Then

- there is an integer $\ m\ $ with $\ 0<m<n\ $ such that $\ 3^n\cdot 2^m-1\ $ is a semiprime.
- there is an integer $\ m\ $ with $\ 0<m<n\ $ such that $\ 3^n\cdot 2^m+1\ $ is a semiprime.
  If we allow also $\ m=0\ $ , the only counterexample for positive integer $\ n\ $ is the minus-case for $\ n=1\ $

> 

The conjecture is true upto $\ n=100\ $

The smallest solutions are listed below.

```
gp > for(n=4,100,m=1;while(bigomega(3^n*2^m-1)<>2,m=m+1);print(n,"  ",m))
```

4  1
5  1
6  1
7  3
8  3
9  1
10  1
11  5
12  5
13  1
14  1
15  4
16  3
17  2
18  1
19  1
20  6
21  1
22  3
23  2
24  1
25  3
26  7
27  2
28  1
29  2
30  1
31  5
32  1
33  2
34  15
35  3
36  1
37  7
38  1
39  1
40  9
41  5
42  19
43  1
44  9
45  1
46  11
47  3
48  5
49  2
50  13
51  4
52  25
53  2
54  1
55  1
56  7
57  2
58  23
59  2
60  7
61  2
62  27
63  1
64  3
65  3
66  13
67  2
68  7
69  2
70  29
71  1
72  5
73  3
74  3
75  14
76  11
77  2
78  1
79  4
80  1
81  20
82  23
83  9
84  1
85  4
86  7
87  1
88  5
89  1
90  1
91  1
92  9
93  7
94  11
95  8
96  55
97  2
98  3
99  14
100  29
gp >

```
gp > for(n=4,100,m=1;while(bigomega(3^n*2^m+1)<>2,m=m+1);print(n,"  ",m))
```

4  3
5  2
6  3
7  2
8  1
9  2
10  1
11  3
12  1
13  8
14  1
15  1
16  3
17  2
18  1
19  2
20  3
21  4
22  1
23  2
24  5
25  2
26  1
27  2
28  3
29  4
30  7
31  10
32  1
33  7
34  1
35  3
36  23
37  6
38  5
39  7
40  11
41  1
42  2
43  5
44  7
45  1
46  1
47  6
48  1
49  24
50  1
51  4
52  8
53  3
54  10
55  18
56  1
57  5
58  10
59  1
60  4
61  5
62  1
63  2
64  1
65  4
66  13
67  3
68  1
69  1
70  1
71  1
72  4
73  5
74  7
75  2
76  1
77  13
78  2
79  5
80  8
81  2
82  1
83  7
84  1
85  8
86  6
87  2
88  5
89  1
90  17
91  31
92  1
93  20
94  7
95  3
96  15
97  12
98  25
99  1
100  3
gp >

To check larger $\ n\ $ , I have to program a more efficient version to find a solution. I will update the post , if I have arrived at a new milestone.

Comment: Great done!!!!! I hope more people in this site could see your outcome. In my opinion, the constantly occurring semiprimes imply some hidden algebraic structure that may reveal itself someday!!!

Comment: The conjecture is still true upto $\ n=200\ $. Nevertheless, I am not sure whether it is true. With increasing $\ n\ $ , the chance for a semiprime will decrease and whether this is compensated by the number of chances is not clear.

Comment: I also see what you've said is well worth considering. Thank you for your work!